# Partitioning a probability on the set of a determinstic variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Are the following probability expressions the same? If so why? In my opinion it is the same but I don't know how one would prove it formally.

$$\mathbb P_S [f(S,z) \geq c, \forall \; z \in A]$$

and

$$\mathbb P_S [(f(S,z) \geq c,\forall\; z \in A_1) \cup (f(S,z) \geq c, \forall \; z \in A_2) ], A = A_1 \cup A_2, A_1 \cap A_2 = \phi$$

What would happen if $A_1 \cap A_2 \neq \phi$?

Comment: What exactly is the set $(f(S,z) \geq c, z \in A_1)$?

Comment: All $S$ for which the inequality holds. I am not sure whether thats the correct way to write  it, but I am assuming it is clear from the context.

Comment: Okay and $z$ is a fixed element or do you take the union over all $z \in A_1$?

Comment: @AndreasLenz I see your point....Ill update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you wrote correctly, I think these two probabilities may be different. In the first event, $f(S,z)$ has to be greater than a certain value on the whole $A$, in the other case, it has to be greater only on parts of $A$,which can be more likely.

Here is a bit of an extreme counter example:
Take $S$ to be the deterministic variable always equal to $1$, $A$ to be simply the set $\{-1,1\}$, $A_1=\{1\}$, $A_2=\{-1\}$ and f(S,z)=S*z. We then have $\mathbb{P}([f(S,z) \geq 0 \ \forall z \in A])=0$, since for $z=-1$, $f(S,z)=-1$, but on the other hand $\mathbb{P}([f(S,z) \geq 0 \ \forall z \in A_1] \cup [f(S,z) \geq 0 \ \forall z \in A_2]) \geq \mathbb{P}([f(S,z) \geq 0 \ \forall z \in A_1])=1$.

If you want your statement to be correct, you need an intersection not a union of the two events. If it is an intersection, then it doesn't matter whether $A_1$ and $A_2$ are disjoint.

In general I'd recommend to first ask yourself what the statement you are making means informally, before you start writting it down with formal notations like I did at the beginning, otherwise it's easy to make simple mistakes.